# Bluetooth multiple UUID's

Tags: android

I implemented a `BluetoothService` where i can connect between two devices. The next step is to connect to devices with different UUID's. I have three Devices:

- Nexus 7
- Nexus 4
- Microcontroller

The Nexus 7 should be able to connect to Nexus 4 and the Microncontroller. The Nexus 4 and the Microcontroller are both having different UUID's. It is not necessary to open a connection to both devices at the same time. Only 1:1 connection needed.

The Nexus 7 is opening the `BluetoothServerSocket` so it needs to no both UUID's.

What do i have to do to make it possible to check if it is the UUID of the Nexus 4 or the UUID of the Microcontroller who tries to connect? Unfortunately i cant do something like this:

```
tempBluetoothServerSocket = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_NEXUS_UUID);
tempBluetoothServerSocket = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_MICRO_UUID);
```

To listen to both UUID's. The same thing for the connection:

```
tempBluetoothSocket = this.bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_NEXUS_UUID | MY_MICRO_UUID);
```

**Edit**

I use the following `BluetoothService`

```
public class BluetoothService extends Thread {
    private static final String TAG = BluetoothService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String NAME = "My_App";
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("d0c722b0-7e15-11e1-b0c4-0800200c9a66");

    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;  
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2;
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;

    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
    private Handler handler = null;
    private AcceptThread acceptThread = null;
    private ConnectThread connectThread = null;
    private ConnectedThread connectedThread = null;
    private int bluetoothState = STATE_NONE;

    public BluetoothService(Handler handler) {
        this.bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        this.bluetoothState = STATE_NONE;
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public synchronized void startConnection() {
        if (this.connectThread != null) {
            this.connectThread.cancel();
            this.connectThread = null;
        }

        if (this.connectedThread != null) {
            this.connectedThread.cancel();
            this.connectedThread = null;
        }

        this.setBluetoothState(STATE_LISTEN);

        if (this.acceptThread == null) {
            this.acceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            this.acceptThread.start();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (this.bluetoothState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
            if (this.connectThread != null) {
                this.connectThread.cancel();
                this.connectThread = null;
            }
        }

        if (this.connectedThread != null) {
            this.connectedThread.cancel();
            this.connectedThread = null;
        }

        this.connectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
        this.connectThread.start();

        this.setBluetoothState(STATE_CONNECTING);
    }

    public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (this.connectThread != null) {
            this.connectThread.cancel();
            this.connectThread = null;
        }

        if (this.connectedThread != null) {
            this.connectedThread.cancel();
            this.connectedThread = null;
        }

        if (this.acceptThread != null) {
            this.acceptThread.cancel(); 
            this.acceptThread = null;
        }

        this.connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
        this.connectedThread.start();

        this.setBluetoothState(STATE_CONNECTED);
        Message msg = this.handler.obtainMessage(Globals.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString(Globals.EXTRA_DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        msg.setData(bundle);

        this.handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    public synchronized void stopConnection() {
        if (this.connectThread != null) {
            this.connectThread.cancel();
            this.connectThread = null;
        }

        if (this.connectedThread != null) {
            this.connectedThread.cancel();
            this.connectedThread = null;
        }

        if (this.acceptThread != null) {
            this.acceptThread.cancel(); 
            this.acceptThread = null;
        }

        this.setBluetoothState(STATE_NONE);
    }

    public void write(byte[] out) {
        ConnectedThread connectedThread = null;

        synchronized (this) {
            if (this.bluetoothState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                return;
            }

            connectedThread = this.connectedThread;
        }

        connectedThread.write(out);
    }

    private void connectionFailed() {
        this.setBluetoothState(STATE_LISTEN);

        Message msg = this.handler.obtainMessage(Globals.MESSAGE_TOAST);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Globals.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");

        msg.setData(bundle);

        this.handler.sendMessage(msg);

        BluetoothService.this.startConnection();
    }

    private void connectionLost() {
        this.setBluetoothState(STATE_LISTEN);

        Message msg = this.handler.obtainMessage(Globals.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString(Globals.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
        msg.setData(bundle);

        this.handler.sendMessage(msg);

        BluetoothService.this.startConnection();
    }

    public synchronized int getBluetoothState() {
        return this.bluetoothState;
    }

    private synchronized void setBluetoothState(int bluetoothState) {
        this.bluetoothState = bluetoothState;
    }

    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        private BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        public AcceptThread() {
            BluetoothServerSocket tempBluetoothServerSocket = null;

            try {
                tempBluetoothServerSocket = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "listen() failed", e);
            }

            this.serverSocket = tempBluetoothServerSocket;
        }

        public void run() {
            this.setName("AcceptThread");

            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            while (bluetoothState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                try {
                    socket = this.serverSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "accept() failed", e);

                    break;
                }

                if (socket != null) {
                    synchronized (BluetoothService.this) {
                        switch (bluetoothState) {
                        case STATE_LISTEN:
                        case STATE_CONNECTING:
                            connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());

                            break;
                        case STATE_NONE:
                        case STATE_CONNECTED:
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                            }

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                this.serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of server failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = null;
        private BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = null;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice) {
            this.bluetoothDevice = bluetoothDevice;

            BluetoothSocket tempBluetoothSocket = null;

            try {
                tempBluetoothSocket = this.bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + "create() failed", e);
            }

            this.bluetoothSocket = tempBluetoothSocket;
        }

        public void run() {
            this.setName("ConnectThread");

            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                this.bluetoothSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);

                connectionFailed();

                try {
                    this.bluetoothSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() socket during connection failure", e2);
                }

                return;
            }

            synchronized (BluetoothService.this) {
                connectThread = null;
            }

            connected(this.bluetoothSocket, this.bluetoothDevice);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                this.bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = null;
        private InputStream inputStream = null;
        private OutputStream outputStream = null;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket) {
            this.bluetoothSocket = bluetoothSocket;

            InputStream tempInputStream = null;
            OutputStream tempOutputStream = null;

            try {
                tempInputStream = this.bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
                tempOutputStream = this.bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            this.inputStream = tempInputStream;
            this.outputStream = tempOutputStream;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes = 0;

            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = this.inputStream.read(buffer);

                    handler.obtainMessage(Globals.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);

                    connectionLost();

                    BluetoothService.this.start();

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                this.outputStream.write(buffer);

                handler.obtainMessage(Globals.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                this.bluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**UUIDS** are for **Services** not for **Devices**. 
This answers both of your questions. you can identify **BluetoothDevice** by its **BluetoothAddress**

Comment: The first tim i read that. All bluetooth tutorials i read where all using UUID's to connect between devices. So how do i connect to devices using the BluetoothAddress and not the UUID? I just need to send some messages from my Nexus 7 to my Nexus 4 or to my Microcontroller

Comment: UUIDs are to connect, thats right. Because You make a connection with Service.
BluetoothDevice class gives you an unique object for different device(differentiate by address). You have to give an address in BluetoothAdapter Class's method getBluetoothDevice("Address") to get your unique device. UUID is for Service.

Comment: I still dont get it. I need to connect to a Device for that i need to connect to a service?? I am able to establisch a connection from my nexus 7 to my nexus 4 thats not the problem but i had to use the same UUID on my nexus 7 and my nexus 4. my micro controller has another uuid so i cant connect to it with my current code. I added the BluetoothService which i use.

Comment: The Bluetooth Chat example from android is also just working with UUID's. There is never something used like Device Adresses.